# Comunicação entre banco de dados e o app em Python - mini sistema de tirar senha

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, python

Olá, estou aprendendo python e resolvi fazer um mini projeto, um sistema simples de fichas, enquanto eu pensava sobre o assunto me veio umas duvidas e não consegui achar quase nada sobre.

O programa funcionaria da seguinte forma, a pessoa tira uma ficha que é cadastrada em um DB, a ficha aparece no painel e no atendente, as duvidas são:

Como o painel e o atendente sabe que a pessoa tirou uma ficha?

Eu teria que criar uma thread em loop perguntando ao DB se foi adicionado algo? onde posso encontrar documentação sobre o assunto? não sei se isso é uma boa solução.

Teria como o DB avisar de alguma forma para o programa se a tabela/coluna foi alterada?
se sim onde posso encontrar documentação sobre o assunto?

Agradeço a todos.

Comment: O que você tentou até então?

Comment: Porque o atendente tem que saber que alguém tirou uma ficha? Normalmente quando atendente fica livre ele pede uma ficha, assim acho que faz mais sentido. Quando ele pedir uma ficha, você vai no banco de dados e procura por fichas criadas e não atendidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se VC estiver usando Django, pode utilizar os [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/). Caso contrario, o mesmo pode ser feito com um ORM independente, como o SQLAlchemy, que possui os [Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html) como o equivalente aos Signals do Django.